# How to delete all rows over 50 count?

Tags: android, sqlite

My table:

```
_id | state | timeStamp
```

I want select all the rows that are of state=0 and order that result by timeStamp.  I than want to delete all items passed a particular limit, say 50 rows.

*Essentially, I don't want there to be more than 50 rows with the state=0

How can I achieve this?  I tried writing one but I'm getting a bit lost...

DELETE FROM table WHERE (state=0) ORDER BY timeStamp

Comment: So you want to truncate your table to 50 rows?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean by events? I assume rows right? Essentially I don't want there to be more than 50 rows with the state=0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `NOT IN` statement with a sub query:
`DELETE FROM table WHERE state = 0 AND _id NOT IN(SELECT _id FROM table WHERE state = 0 ORDER BY timeStamp LIMIT 50);`

What it does is select all rows where `state = 0` and then removes the 50 first rows that has `state = 0` all while ordering on timeStamp

Comment: yes, I was essentially getting lost with the sub query when I was trying... So I understand what you have there but it feels like the first and last SELECT command are repeated.  What does the - mean?

Comment: Sorry, the minus is wrong, I'm looking for the correct query. Give me a minute :)

Comment: @Nicklas shouldn't you be using NOT IN instead of IN?

Comment: you also missed the ORDER BY timestamp inside the SELECT

Comment: That's perfect! I got to give it a try... So this is going keep the first 50 items and discard the rest?

Comment: Thanks, that worked perfectly! I just had to add DESC to the ORDER BY and it worked perfectly! :)

Comment: Yes, it will keep XX amount where XX is defined in `LIMIT XX`. Glad it worked :)

Answer (score 1):

You can find what the time stamp is for the 50th row and then do a delete statement for rows whose state = 0 and whose timestamp is older (or newer, whichever applies here) than the time stamp you found.

Comment: thanks for your approach idea, I think it makes complete sence.  I'm still not sure how to write a complex DELETE query.  Essentially hopefully with help of this forum I can get this working with one query and understand how it works. :)